# Plot Histogram in a matrix layout to profile clusters

Tags: r, layout, ggplot2

I am trying to write a big function to perform the profiling of clusters.

Currently, I am struggling with one of the last task which is:
**Plot the histograms in a matrix layout where the rows represent clusters and columns represent variables.**

Considering the following sample:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50,5), y = rnorm(50, 10))
```

The objective is to use the following plots and merge them in a matrix layout:

```
library(ggplot2)

plot11 <- ggplot() +
        geom_histogram(data = df,
                       aes(x = x, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                       position = "identity",
                       fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
        xlab("1,1")

plot12 <- ggplot() +
        geom_histogram(data = df,
                       aes(x = x, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                       position = "identity",
                       fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
        xlab("1,2")

plot13 <- ggplot() +
        geom_histogram(data = df,
                       aes(x = x, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                       position = "identity",
                       fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
        xlab("1,3")

plot21 <- ggplot() +
        geom_histogram(data = df,
                       aes(x = x, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                       position = "identity",
                       fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
        xlab("2,1")

plot22 <- ggplot() +
        geom_histogram(data = df,
                       aes(x = x, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                       position = "identity",
                       fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
        xlab("2,2")

plot23 <- ggplot() +
        geom_histogram(data = df,
                       aes(x = x, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                       position = "identity",
                       fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
        xlab("2,3")


plot31 <- ggplot() +
        geom_histogram(data = df,
                       aes(x = x, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                       position = "identity",
                       fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
        xlab("3,1")


plot32 <- ggplot() +
        geom_histogram(data = df,
                       aes(x = x, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                       position = "identity",
                       fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
        xlab("3,2")
```

For each plot, the first index represent the row and the second represent the column. Therefore, `plot32` should be visualized in `row = 3 and col = 2`.

#### The solution needs to use indices in order to refer to plot objects

For example,

```
for(cluster in 1:k) {
    for(variable in 1:3) {
        #add plot paste0("plot",cluster,variable) to the matrix layout in row = cluster and col = variable
    }
}
```

Here is how the plot should be arranged:
[image]

Clearly, the final visualization is more articulated than this because

- plots are sorted based on the relative importance for that cluster
- for each cluster, there is plot only for a textual description of that cluster
- in the case of categorical variables, a piechart will be used

However, the main issue is to understand how to create the matrix layout where I can insert all the plots.

### Update

[image]
this is what I obtain following your suggestions.

Comment: Did you try something with  `multiplot ` ?

Comment: I tried multiplot but I have not been able to obtain the result. Maybe I was doing something wrong because the plot where "overlaying" one another

Comment: edit: multiplot can work but you must manually write the ggplot object name  inside the function. This means that I cannot dynamically manipulate the plot

Comment: Why do you mean by "dynamically" ? If the number of plots is fixed, I don't see your point.

Comment: Obviously I cannot write multiplot(plot11, plot12, plot13, plot14, plot15, plot21, plot22, plot23, plot24, plot25, plot31, plot32, plot33, plot34, plot35, plot41, plot42, plot43, plot44, plot45, ..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................)

I need to find a dynamic and automatic way to do this. Dynamic because the order of appearence is determined by another function.

Comment: So, you can build a string, pasting  `multiplot(` and the orded id of your plots, .. and then use `eval` ..

Comment: I tried this approach but it does not work. It exclusively evaluate the last plot in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about with cowplot

```
library("cowplot")
plot_grid(plot11,plot12,plot13,plot21,ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

or you can pass a list of plots if you could populate it with your function:

```
plotList<-list(plot11,plot12,plot13,plot21)
plot_grid(plotlist=plotList,ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: the problem of cowplot is that it is not dynamic nor automatic. As I wrote, the solution cannot require to write "(plot11, plot12, plot13, plot14, plot15, plot21, plot22, plot23, plot24, plot25, plot31, plot32, plot33, plot34, plot35, plot41, plot42, plot43, plot44, plot45, ............................................................‌​....................‌​....................‌​....................‌​....................‌​....................‌​....................‌​....................‌​....................‌​..)"

Comment: if you could populate a list of plots using your function, you could pass this list into plot_grid, check my upadted answer if this helps you

Comment: the idea of using list() might seem correct however the plot are not properly displayed

Answer (score 1):

What I sugest is that you deal with a conveinant form to create a string and use it like that (the code for multiplot function is not mine, of course)  :

```
 multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, file, cols=1, layout=NULL) {
  require(grid)

  # Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
  plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)

  numPlots = length(plots)

  # If layout is NULL, then use 'cols' to determine layout
  if (is.null(layout)) {
    # Make the panel
# ncol: Number of columns of plots
# nrow: Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols
layout <- matrix(seq(1, cols * ceiling(numPlots/cols)),
                 ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots/cols))
  }

  if (numPlots==1) {
print(plots[[1]])

  } else {
# Set up the page
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow(layout), ncol(layout))))

# Make each plot, in the correct location
for (i in 1:numPlots) {
  # Get the i,j matrix positions of the regions that contain this subplot
  matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))

  print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,
                                  layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
    }
  }
}

string_plots <- "multiplot(plotlist = list(plot11,plot12, plot13, plot21, plot22, plot23, plot31, plot32), cols = 3)"

eval(parse(text=string_plots))
```